# How to add "ref" as string name in C#

Tags: string, entity, ref

I want to name my string value 'ref' without any capital letters. Since ref is a value i can't do that.

[image: 'ref' is a class. I want it to be a name.]

[image: 'Ref' with a capital doesn't work in this scenario]

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, `ref` is a keyword and can't be used directly in this manner.  The *usual* advice is "don't use keywords as names".  For things like deserializing JSON which has a property called `"ref"` you can often get around it with mapping your otherwise-named property to that JSON property with configuration or a property attribute, depending on the JSON serialization library you're using.

But if you really do need to use a keyword as a name like this, or if it's just easier than mucking around with things like serialization libraries, the language does provide a way to do that.  Simply prefix the name with an `@`:

```
public string @ref { get; set; }
```

This approach is most commonly seen in things like Razor web pages where we need to specify client-side HTML attributes in server-side C# objects, and a common HTML attribute name is `class`.